# Transaction Decoding on Fantom. I can't extract the data I need

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, javascript, txpool, fantom

This is the first question I post here so I hope my question asked properly.

I'm scanning the Fantom mempool searching for specific types of functions that interfere with pairs liquidity. I'm having some problems getting out the data I need from this aggregator transaction: https://ftmscan.com/tx/0x7a7b9ad1453a2dd33e2aeb34efa02cceff523383c9007fc96458f3952bec5db5

The transaction happened via FireBird Aggregator and the data I'm interested in is the swap on SpookySwap between WFTM and MIM. My problem is that when I decode the transaction data using contractInterface.parseTransaction({ data: txData }) I only get to see the exchange between USDC and MIM, their values and not much more. I can't see the exact function I need (the swap on the Logs tab in position 11).

So my question is: how do I read the data about that specific swap?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Perhaps there is no USDC and MIM direct trading pool in Spooky LP (spLP), and it needs to be exchanged indirectly through other tokens. For example, WFTM, and what token exchange is indirectly used is determined by the algorithm of the pool.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Ok I get what you are saying, but if the amount out in MIM that I read in mempool is correct that means that all the routes have already been done, right? What I am trying to understand is if those routes are in the mempool decoded data, maybe nested in the transaction or somewhere

Comment: yes.  
function swap(IAggregationExecutor caller, SwapDescription calldesc, bytes calldata data)
The route is in the 0x5BAB9d61f84630A76fA9e2f67739f2da694B5402 contract code or the data in the parameters of the swap function. Since the source code of the 0x5BAB... contract is not open source, it cannot be further determined. I think that the routing path is most likely in the data in the parameters of the swap function.